# how to return a view with querystring parameters in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, querystringparameter

Very basic but not sure how to do since i am new to mvc.

I have to return a view based on a if condition.

if true, i should return a view with a guid value as querystring parameter 
else
return a different view.

```
public ActionResult Act(Guid approvalCode)
    {
        bool result = businessProvider.CheckLinkValidity(approvalCode);
        if (result == true)
        {
            return View("Act"); //here i need to pass approvalcode as querystring param
          //want to do like
          //return View("Act"+"?code="+approvalcode) 
        }
        return View("LinkExpiredView");
    }
```

I need to render the view like:

~\ResetController\Act?code= someguidvalue

Comment: Instead of query string, you can set the value of your GUID into viewbag and access it your view. ViewBag.GuidVariable = Guid_Value;

Answer (score 12):

I actually don't understand why you need query string.

Without it you can do like this:

```
return View("Act", new { code = "your-guid" });
```

If you still need it one of possible ways `RedirectToAction` method:

```
return RedirectToAction("Act", new { code = "your-guid" });
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But RedirectToAction doesn't work.

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ViewBag to set some value https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx